# How to retrieve multiple XML Nodes, stored as CLOB in DB2, as separate records?

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I have a table where there are some codes saved as clobs in DB2 7.

This is the table content:

```
| CODEID | CODEXML      |CODECREATIONTS                  |
|--------|--------------|--------------------------------|
|      1 |       <CLOB> | January, 14 2015 22:33:49+0000 |
|      2 |       <CLOB> | January, 15 2015 22:33:49+0000 |
```

Where each clob has an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT_MODULE Ver="1" VerComment="This is a script created for testing">
    <LANGUAGE>CustomLanguage</LANGUAGE>
    <SCRIPT>
        <LINE>function print()</LINE>
        <LINE>{</LINE>
        <LINE>\t return \"I am being called";</LINE>
        <LINE>}</LINE>
    <SCRIPT>
    <ATTRIBUTES></ATTRIBUTES>
</ROOT_MODULE>
```

When I issue this query:

```
select
    xmlCodeTable.lineCode
from
    myCodes,
    XMLTABLE(           
            '$xmlDoc/ROOT_MODULE/SCRIPT' PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT myCodes.codeXML) AS "xmlDoc"
            COLUMNS
            lineCode varchar(50) PATH 'LINE[1]'
         ) AS xmlCodeTable
where codeID = 1
```

I get this:

```
| lineCode        |
|-----------------|
| function print()|
```

What I need, is to get this:

```
| lineCode                                 |
|------------------------------------------|
| function print()                         |
| {                                        |
| \t return &quot;I am being called&quot;; |
| }                                        |
```

When I get rid of the "[1]" in the query path, it shows me an error.

How do I do what I need?

Thanks.

Note: This is something that is already implemented, so I can't change the design and just do a proper versioning system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath expression `LINE` in your case returns a sequence of `LINE` elements, which is obviously incompatible with `VARCHAR`. One way to address this is to rewrite your query like so:

```
select
    xmlCodeTable.lineCode
from
    myCodes,
    XMLTABLE(           
            '$xmlDoc/ROOT_MODULE/SCRIPT/LINE' 
            PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT myCodes.codeXML) AS "xmlDoc"
            COLUMNS
            lineCode varchar(50) PATH '.'
         ) AS xmlCodeTable
where codeID = 1
```

If you also need something from the `LINE` parent element, use the relative XPath:

```
...
COLUMNS
lineCode varchar(50) PATH '.',
lang varchar(50)     PATH '../../LANGUAGE
...
```

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio. I can't test it right now, but would that give me all the lines without having to create a union all to get all the contents of the line nodes?